# $T^{-1}$ linear and bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\to Y$ be linear and bounded operator such that there exists a constant $C\gt 0$ so that $||Tx||_Y \ge C||x||_{X}$ for all $x \in X$ . Is $T^{-1}$ linear and bounded operator ? 
i tried to show $T$ is bijective.Because if $T$ is bijective ,$T^{-1}$ exists and so it is bounded and linear. Am i wrong ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$? Finite-dimensional spaces, Hilbert spaces, Banach spaces? In Hilbert spaces, for instance, there exist isometries that are not bijective (e.g., the right-shift in $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$).

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are any spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T$ with the condition you gave is clearly one-to-one, as $Tx = 0$ implies 
$$ \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{x}_X \le \frac 1C \norm{Tx}_Y = 0. $$
But $T$ need not be onto $Y$, as the example $T(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ on $\ell^2$ shows (note that $\norm{Tx}_2 = \norm x_2$ in this case).

But, $T$ is onto $TX$ (obviously) and hence $T^{-1} \colon TX \to X$ is defined. Note, that only from this we cannot derive that $T^{-1}$ is continuous (it is linear as an inverse to a linear operator), but here the condition comes into play again. Let $y \in TX$, then 
$$ \norm{y}_Y \ge C\norm{T^{-1}y}_X \iff \norm{T^{-1}y}_X \le \frac 1C \norm y_Y $$
hence $T^{-1}$ is continuous with $\norm{T^{-1}} \le \frac 1C$.